# How to install freeRTOS on a laptop without win32 or linux port to get real time behavior?

Tags: freertos

I'm getting started with freeRTOS. I went through the documentation provided in freeRTOS.org, and had some practice with some demo projects. My question is how to install freeRTOS without using the win32 port (since it is only an emulator that doesn't provide real time behaviour)? Is it possible to install freeRTOS as a standalone OS, or is it necessary to use linux kernel or windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FreeRTOS is a real time operating system kernel. It's not a fully blown OS, it's just the kernel. You don't "install" FreeRTOS like you would windows or a ubuntu distro on an x86 PC. You build a project and use freeRTOS to schedule tasks, manage memory resources etc. In general, you need a different microcontroller/processor than one you're developing on as your platform.

If you want to use only your laptop, then you'll need to simulate a "target" processor (that's what that option is). You won't be able to achieve "real time" results (windows will get in the way), but you can get pretty close.

The first thing I'd do is get an eval kit for whatever microcontroller you want to actually use/target/develop on.